# Worklight development server stop automatically

Tags: eclipse, worklight-server, worklight-studio

The problem is that the **Worklight development server** stop automatically without any error logged or reasons after few minutes that it is started.

My configuration is as follow:

- Win8.1 machine with **8g** of RAM
- Eclipse: Kepler Service Release 2 (or Luna it doesn't solve the
  problem) with **4g** as Xmx JVM option in the *.ini* file
- WL:   6.2.0.01-20150105-1620 (any newer version doesn't
  solve the problem rather it seems to be worsen)
- JAVA: java version "1.7.0_79" - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15) - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Here is the log of the server:

```
    ...[cut the starting log]...
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://127.0.0.1:10080/Mobile/
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application Mobile has stopped successfully.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://127.0.0.1:10080/worklightadmin/
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application WorklightServices has stopped successfully.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://127.0.0.1/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application _MobileBrowserSimulator has stopped successfully.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://127.0.0.1:10080/worklightconsole/
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application WorklightConsole has stopped successfully.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://127.0.0.1:10080/_analytics/
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application _analytics has stopped successfully.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://127.0.0.1:10080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
    [AUDIT   ] WTRN0105I: The transaction service has shutdown successfully with no transactions requiring recovery.
    [AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server worklight stopped after 1 minutes, 30.815 seconds.
```

The WL jvm options xml file here:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dwas.debug.mode=true
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=10777
-Dcom.ibm.websphere.ras.inject.at.transform=true
-Dcom.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.client.rest.readTimeout=180000
-Dibm.worklight.admin.db.type=DERBY
-Xmx1024m
-Dos.name=Windows
-DwlDevEnv.enableCreateTables=true
-Djmx.remote.x.client.connection.check.period=0
-DwlSyncStart=false
```

I tried to update Worlight, Eclipse, Java but nothing appened. The server keep stopping after few minutes.

I just followed a similiar question's answer:

> Go to Control Panel, then to Power Management, there choose "never" near "system on idle". This will differ a bit depending on the specific Windows OS version.
>   but nothing changes.

Any suggestions? I think that it is Eclipse itself that shutting the WL server down.

Comment: First, upgrade your worklight studio build, and do not downgrade just because you do not see a difference. Your build is **old**. Upgrade. Use a new workspace in Eclipse. Provide the full messages.log file

Comment: I also tried with the 6.2.0.01-20151008 version from fix central, with a fresh eclipse (Kepler and Luna) installation and a fresh workspace but nothing changes. The server kepps stopping automatically.

Comment: Which eclipse type are you using? Should be JavaEE. Also, are those entries in the IBM file there by default or did you add those?

Comment: The eclipse version is: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 2 The IBM Worlight jvm.options file I think that contains only the standard entries but I'm not sure of this

Answer (score 0):

Can you follow the steps and try if it helps

1. Make a back up of WorklightServerConfig folder which should be in the workspace
2. Exit eclipse and delete the above folder
3. Start the eclipse again

Also re-adjust your jvm.options as required per your requirement but before that wait and see if the server is stable.